# Jquery problems in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, invalid-argument, jquery-1.3.2

Jquery runs fine in Safari and Firefox. In IE8 (using the Developer Tools), I get the error: "Could not get the position property. Invalid argument jquery-1.3.2.js, line 12 character 12949". Using debugging, the script highlights the characters {J[G]=K}.

I have no idea what this does, but it seems to cause the problem! The result is when a thumbnail image is clicked in one of my galleries, the image does not open in IE8. If anyone understands this or how to correct it, I'd be very grateful! See the problem in action (or not) on my website www.blueshiftgallery.com  Many thanks!

Comment: Incidently, you should be putting your `<script>` tags in your `<head>` section

Comment: Thanks Gausie. I'm just a bungling amateur. I'll try to get my mind around it and sort out my code, as that's most likely to be the problem!

Comment: Gausie. I've tried moving the script, which still works fine in safari. The thumbnails open an image within the frameset if you click the Captify caption, but not the image, And the 'View' button does not work. Both work fine in Safari. Try the Dreamscapes gallery at www.blueshiftgallery to see what I mean. Thanks! Jurgen.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be with the Captify plugin. The same issue occurs on IE8 on the demo page - http://thirdroute.com/projects/captify/

Clicking the image does not work. However, clicking the caption text which appears when you hover does work.

Comment: Eeek... I'm actually the developer of Captify. I'd love to help and get this fixed. What's weird is: I'm running IE8 and the script runs just fine w/o error. What version of IE are you using? (I'm on 8.0.7100.0)

Comment: HI Rezler and Brian. I'm a complete amateur at this and I've been told me code is all over the place! I'll have a look to see if can sort it out and get back to you. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Hi Brian. I've tried moving the script, which still works fine in safari. The thumbnails open an image within the frameset if you click the Captify caption, but not the image, And the 'View' button does not work. Both work fine in Safari. Try the Dreamscapes gallery at www.blueshiftgallery to see what I mean. Thanks! Jurgen.

Comment: I'm on version 8.0.7600.16385

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar problem, my code worked in all browsers except IE (the usual story).

I was getting the same error message when I was using jquery to pop-up a dialog box.

Eventually I figured out it was because I was using the pos parameter with values containing NaN rather than integers.

This was due to the fact I was using `window.innerWidth` when populating my pos array. The solution was to use `$(window).width()` instead.

Technically I don't think these are equivalent as one gets the inner width while the other gets the total width but for my purposes it was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is why I had why I encountered this same problem.

```
var visitorPanelHeight = $('#VisitorPanel').css('height').replace(/px/i, '');
```

I was attempting to grab a height and strip off the 'px' from the value that was never set through .css.  This returned 'auto'.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for me it is solved this way and is working correctly in IE8 and IE7

just remove or comment out position property which shape the touching  of the tip.

here is my Qtip constructor.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.qtip.styles.mystyle = {

        background: '#A2D959',
        color: 'black',
        textAlign: 'right', direction: 'rtl',          
        name: 'dark' 
         , tip: 'topLeft' 
        // , position: { corner: { target: 'bottomRight', tooltip: 'topLeft'} }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tt21,#tt22,#tt4,#ttMobile,#ImgEmail,.ttFaname').qtip({ style: { name: 'mystyle'} });
    });
</script>
```